# Making UserId as Identity to access unique data from DB based on UserId

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application,User logs in and after that I am fetching his data from Sql server DB.Here I am using UserId as Identity. Based on UserId How to get his data using query.
 In registration page,user fills his all Information.After he logs In, in dashboard page how to fetch his data(Dashboard details as per project)using UserId  which is made Identity to get unique information.
Please suggest some options?

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not a tutorial site. Your best bet is Microsoft [ASP.Net Site](https://www.asp.net/identity) itself.

Answer (score 0):

To get the UserId while in the scope of a controller, that is a property of Controller:

```
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        }
```

Comment: I am maintaining 2 tables in sql server.one is The TCP_Data and other is User_Data where UserId is common in both tables.So using only UserId,I want to get each users (unique)data.Now for example 5th user UserId is 5.

Comment: for 6th user,how to I write query to get data from  TCP_Data table using UserId.which is 6 in this case.

Comment: I must have misunderstood your original question. So are you using Entity Framework. Like the code generated by Visual Studio with ApplicationDBContext?

Comment: No..I am not using that

Comment: How are you accessing your database?